# Bootstrap 5 Modal not showing up

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to display a Modal using Angular's Bootstrap 5 but it looks like that the Modal has no element on the browser.
Here is the code used:
Modal.html

```
<ng-template modalTemplate>
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="title">
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" formControlName="description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</ng-template>
```

Where modal is called

```
<div id="outside-container" class="card">
    <div id="list">
        *code*
    </div>
</div>

<app-modal-edit-note #modalEditNote></app-modal-edit-note>
```

How the modal looks after pressing the button:

[modal_displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAeKv.png)

HTML code on the Browser:

[html_modal_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Mof.png)

Comment: Use [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap#readme) - [example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/overlay/modal/modal.component.html#L7-L43) - [demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/overlays/modals)